# How to move ChildDrawable in LayerDrawable

Tags: android, user-interface

here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_layer_drawable2);
    ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i);
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{dra(this, R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp), new Rect()});
    ld.setLayerInsetTop(1, 200);
    ld.setLayerInsetLeft(1, 200);
    i.setImageDrawable(ld);
}
```

here is Rect

```
class Rect extends Drawable {
        Context c;

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            c = getApplicationContext();
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setStrokeWidth(2);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p.setColor(col(c, R.color.colorAccent));
            canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, p);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

the output is:

[image]

I hope move rectangle to the right-bottom of ImageView, how to do that?

when i use `setLayerInsetTop`, it only change rectangle's size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason, in Rect class `canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, p)`, it will force rect locate in pointer (0, 0), I can change "0,0" to other